# Celery / RabbitMQ - Find out the No Acks - Unacknowledged messages

Tags: rabbitmq, celery, django-celery

I am trying to figure out how to get information on unacknowledged messages.  Where are these stored? In playing with celery inspect it seems that once a message gets acknowledged it processes through and you can follow the state.  Assuming you have a results backend then you can see the results of it.  But from the time you apply delay until it get's acknowledged it's in a black hole.

1. Where are noAcks stored?
2. How do I find out how "deep" is the noAcks list?  In other words how many are there and where is my task in the list.

While not exactly germane to the problem here is what I'm working with.

```
from celery.app import app_or_default

app = app_or_default()
inspect = app.control.inspect()

# Now if I want "RECEIVED" jobs.. 
data = inspect.reserved()

# or "ACTIVE" jobs.. 
data = inspect.active()

# or "REVOKED" jobs.. 
data = inspect.revoked()

# or scheduled jobs.. (Assuming these are time based??)
data = inspect.scheduled()

# FILL ME IN FOR UNACK JOBS!!
# data = inspect.??

# This will never work for tasks that aren't in one of the above buckets..
pprint.pprint(inspect.query_task([tasks]))
```

I really appreciate your advice and help on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are those tasks in `inspect.reserved()` that have `'acknowleged': False`

```
from celery.app import app_or_default

app = app_or_default()
inspect = app.control.inspect()

# those that have been sent to a worker and are thus reserved
# from being sent to another worker, but may or may not be acknowledged as received by that worker
data = inspect.reserved()

{'celery.tasks': [{'acknowledged': False,
               'args': '[]',
               'delivery_info': {'exchange': 'tasks',
                                 'priority': None,
                                 'routing_key': 'celery'},
               'hostname': 'celery.tasks',
               'id': '527961d4-639f-4002-9dc6-7488dd8c8ad8',
               'kwargs': '{}',
               'name': 'globalapp.tasks.task_loop_tick',
               'time_start': None,
               'worker_pid': None},
              {'acknowledged': False,
               'args': '[]',
               'delivery_info': {'exchange': 'tasks',
                                 'priority': None,
                                 'routing_key': 'celery'},
               'hostname': 'celery.tasks',
               'id': '09d5b726-269e-48d0-8b0e-86472d795906',
               'kwargs': '{}',
               'name': 'globalapp.tasks.task_loop_tick',
               'time_start': None,
               'worker_pid': None},
              {'acknowledged': False,
               'args': '[]',
               'delivery_info': {'exchange': 'tasks',
                                 'priority': None,
                                 'routing_key': 'celery'},
               'hostname': 'celery.tasks',
               'id': 'de6d399e-1b37-455c-af63-a68078a9cf7c',
               'kwargs': '{}',
               'name': 'globalapp.tasks.task_loop_tick',
               'time_start': None,
               'worker_pid': None}],
 'fastlane.tasks': [],
 'images.tasks': [],
 'mailer.tasks': []}
```

Comment: Nice - Where is this documented?

Comment: I just started from your code and then noticed that the unacked ones were in reserved. yesterday I discovered that if you install celery 3.0.11 it will install billiard 3.x which doesn't actually work with celery 3.0; so the tasks were not acknowledging and had no start time. billiard < 3 works. moral of the story: always pin or freeze your dependencies.

Comment: This is great.  Thanks I don't know why I didn't see or think of this earlier this earlier.  Can you confirm if this working with Celery 3.1x (Current)?

Comment: celery is a confusing mess of options, documentations, multiple methods of doing things and many many versions. no idea if it works on 3.1 sorry :)

Answer (score 3):

After hours of reviewing celery I've come to the conclusion that it's just not possible using pure celery.  However it is possible to loosely track the entire process.  Here is the code I used to look up the unacknowledged count.  Most of this can be done using the utilities in celery.

**I still am unable to query the underlying unacknowledged tasks by id but..**

If you have the [RabbitMQ management plug-in](https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html) installed you can query the API

```
    data = {}
    base_url = "http://localhost:55672"
    url = base_url + "/api/queues/{}/".format(vhost)
    req = requests.get(url, auth=(settings.RABBITMQ_USER, settings.RABBITMQ_PASSWORD))
    if req.status_code != 200:
        log.error(req.text)
    else:
        request_data = req.json()
        for queue in request_data:
            # TODO if we know what queue the task is then we can nail this.
            if queue.get('name') == "celery":
                data['state'] = "Unknown"
                if queue.get('messages'):
                    data['messages'] = queue.get('messages')
                    data['messages_ready'] = queue.get('messages_ready')
                    data['messages_unacknowledged'] = queue.get('messages_unacknowledged')
                break
    return data
```